# Are there any resources that discuss the relevance of mathematical fields/problems to philosophy?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

I've been enjoying reading Scott Aaronson's paper *Why Philosophers Should Care About Computational Complexity*. The paper discusses how the field of computational complexity is of major relevance to some philosophical problems including the induction problem, the computational theory of mind, AI, etc. I was wondering if there are any similar resources which discuss the relevance of some other mathematical fields (e.g. topology, analysis, or number theory) to philosophy.

Just to emphasize, I'm not talking about mathematical philosophy resources. What I'm looking for is application of mathematics in philosophy.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is suitable..But Eugenia Chengs short paper Mathematics, morally is very entertaining and demonstrate the different modes of thinking btw. mathematics and philosophy..http://eugeniacheng.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/cheng-morality.pdf

Comment: Some suggestions, not as pointed as Aaronson's essay, [A mathematician's response to the philosophy of mathematics](http://settheory.net/philosophy-of-mathematics), [Corfield, Towards a Philosophy 
of Real Mathematics](https://www.ams.org/notices/201110/rtx111001454p.pdf).